# How can I select variations for an animation? E.g. multiple types of death animations

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

How can I select variations for an animation? E.g. multiple types of death animations.

For example if I have 3 different death animations for my characters.

I am talking more than one character sharing the same animation controller and I would like to vary their animations to make them look less alike.

Is this possible or must I give them different animation controllers?

So imagine I have 3 different death animations, there should always be 1/3 chance one of them is chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [animation parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) combined with [blend trees](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html).
Basically, you can decide upon the animation graph the values to associate with which animation and then by script control the animation behaviour.
With code just as simple as:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("Death",1f);
```

Comment: Not relevant in the entirely same way. But a cool thing I discovered along the way of research is Animation Layers: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html. Works great for blending animations such as getting hit and moving.